# Why are objects default initialized but primitives aren't in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization

Why are primitives not default initialized but objects are in C++? For example:

```
class Foo {
  void Method() {
    int w(); // initialized to 0
    int x; // uninitialized
    std::vector<int> y(); // initialized to empty vector
    std::vector<int> z; // initialized to empty vector
  }
}
```

In this case, `w` and `y` are declared with parentheses, and so are initialized, and `z` is declared without, and gets its no argument default constructor called, but `x` remains uninitialized. Why is this?

Comment: `z` does have its  default constructor called, its just not obvious. Also, with `y` and `w` I'm pretty sure you declared a function, not a variable.

Comment: `int w();` is a declaration for a function named `w` without parameters and returning `int`. It is not a variable definition. Similarly `y` is declared as function returning `std::vector<int>` without parameters. I think you might want to use `{}` instead of `()` to demonstrate your question.

Comment: @ChrisMM ah yes, the most vexing parse.

Comment: Because there's no such thing as default initialization of anything in C.

Comment: recommended watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfP4VAK21zc

Comment: refer [GOTW : Variable Initialization](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no initializer for an object, the object is *default initialized* [[dcl.init]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#12). If the initializer is `()`, the object is *value initialized* [[dcl.init]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#11). Default initialization of an object of class type (like `std::vector<int>`) invokes the default constructor while default initialization for an object of type `int` means no initialization [[dcl.init]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#7). Value initialization will also call the default constructor for objects of class type that have one (like `std::vector<int>` does), but for objects of type `int`, value initializtion means *zero initialization* [[dcl.init]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#8). And zero initialization for an `int` does actually mean that the `int` is initialized to zero [[dcl.init]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#6)…

As has already been pointed out in the comments,

```cpp
int w();
```

and

```cpp
std::vector<int> y();
```

are not in fact definitions of a local variable, but rather declarations of two functions `w` and `y` that take no arguments and return an `int` and an `std::vector<int>` respectively (the infamous [*most vexing parse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)). Nevertheless, there are cases where it is possible to use `()` as an actual initializer, so let's modify your example a bit to demonstrate the behavior you were asking about:

```cpp
class Foo
{
    int w;
    std::vector<int> y;

    Foo()
      : w(),  // value initialized == zero initialized for int
        y()   // value initialized == default initialized for std::vector<int>
    {
        int x; // default initialized == uninitialized for int
        std::vector<int> z; // default initialized
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The "why" here simplifies to "Because C++ was trying to keep performance and behaviors C compatible where it could". When you're selling a new, relatively low-level language that (at least initially) was mostly a superset of C, you don't want to say "If you compile existing C code as C++, it's always slower!" C doesn't zero-initialize primitives by default; as long as the code *eventually* assigns a value to them before reading from them, that's fine, and C++ follows the same pattern.